# Prevent MS Excel 2010 scrolling left before colum A

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet, when I am in column A and go left one it moves to column CB, how can I prevent this happening?

Comment: Appears to happen when I lock cells and protect the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column you want to protect (in your case the column A), go to "*Data*" menu and then to "*Group*"

[image: Group column menu]

Now hide the column with the "*-*" symbol; then go to "*Review*" menu and click to "*protect sheet*"

You can block with or without password, it's up to you.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer, I don't want to hide/group/protect column and I don't want to be able to go left of column A.